# WPF/XAML - hide image if another control's text property is empty/not set

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

i'm new to wpf and this is my first attempt of creating a custom user control. its purpose is to display two values (myText1 and myText2) with their corresponding images (myimage1, myimage2). sometimes, one of these values is not set and therefore oneimage should be hidden as well. here's my code so far:

Window1.xaml

```
<local:myControl myText2="Hello World!" />
```

myControl.xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myControl,Path=myText1}" />
<Image Source="myimage1.jpg" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myControl,Path=myText2}" />
<Image Source="myimage2.jpg" />
```

myText1 was not set in window1.xaml and therefore the textblock remains empty. but the image is still displayed. which lines of code am i missing to hide the image if myText1 (or myText2) was not set in window1.xaml?

Answer (score 2):

You have write converter for text to visibility

```
public class TextToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string && targetType == typeof(bool))
        {
            if (value.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
                 return Visibility.Hidden;
            else
                return Visibility.Hidden;
         }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Visibility && targetType == typeof(string))
        {
            if ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                return "Text";
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in XAML < TextToVisibilityConverter x:Key="myCnverter"/>

Comment: I think your code is a bit off in the if(value.toString().Equals(string.empty) section the else should be Visibility.Visible shouldn't it?

Also would it make more sense to do String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) in that conditional?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of small mistakes there:

```
if (value is string && targetType == typeof(bool))  
    {            
    if (value.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))  
        return Visibility.Hidden;  
    else  
        return Visibility.Hidden;  
    }
```

Should be

```
if (value is string && targetType == typeof(Visibility))  
    {            
    if (value.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))  
        return Visibility.Hidden;  
    else  
        return Visibility.Visible;  
    }
```

You need the following usings:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
```

You may also consider returning `Visibility.Collapsed` rather than `Visibility.Hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the right converter then is easy. 
And not much answers also got that Text.IsEmpty is available for TextBlock Text property

I created a BooleanVisibilityConverter that depends on a parameter the boolean against True or False.
Gives you the !True flexibility that is missing on xaml.

```
public class BooleanVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{       
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility v = Visibility.Collapsed;
        bool checkValue = true;
        if(parameter != null)
        {
            checkValue = Boolean.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        }
        if(value.Equals(checkValue))
        {
            v = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return v;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml import that namespace into:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:ConvertersNamespace"
```

Create the converter into the Resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <conv:BooleanVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2vis" />        
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then just use into your design:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myControl,Path=myText1}" x:Name="txtBlock"/>
<Image Source="myimage1.jpg"  
       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtBlock,Path=Text.IsEmpty,
                     Converter={StaticResource bool2vis},ConverterParameter=False}"/>
```